# creating a custom td tr table for Displaying the Data

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I have the following string and i want to split that string to display data in table format but the way i want to display is not working, Here is the data and here is how it should look like

```
vendorname- #name#: city-#city#: state-#state#:zip-#zip#:in network-#innetwork#
```

i want to create the above as the following table:

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td>vendorname</td><td>#vendorname#</td>
     <td>city</td><td>#city#</td>
     <td>state</td><td>#state#</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>zip</td><td>#zip#</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

trying to create 6 columns in one TR

Here is try so far

```
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="6" bordercolor="#CCCCCC;">
  <tr>
    <cfloop index="aPair" list="#Demo_Details#" delimiters=":">
    <cfset Key= listFirst(aPair,"-")>
    <cfif listLen(apair,"-") gt 1>
      <cfset value= listLast(aPair,"-")>
      <cfelse>
      <cfset value = "">
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>
    <td><strong>#key#</strong></td>
    <td>#value#</td>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is not generating the columns as expected, it is showing everything in single line

Comment: Your sample shows that you want the zip on a separate row.  That means you need some conditional logic to start a new row if your key is zip.

Comment: your example has one row for vendorname, city, state, but another row for zip.  Your code doesn't reflect that - you may be better populating a struct from your list, which you then use to output the specific parts in the two rows, as required

Comment: Sorry, just duplicating what @DanBracuk said, hadn't seen his comment

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
<cfset Vendor = "">
<cfset City = "">
<cfset State = "">
<cfset ZIP = "">

<cfloop index="aPair" list="#Demo_Details#" delimiters=":">
    <cfset Key= listFirst(aPair,"-")>
    <cfif listLen(apair,"-") gt 1>
        <cfset SetVariable(key, listLast(aPair,"-")>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>    

<cfoutput>
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="6" bordercolor="#CCCCCC;">
<tr>
      <td>vendorname</td><td>#vendorname#</td>
      <td>city</td><td>#city#</td>
      <td>state</td><td>#state#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>zip</td><td>#zip#</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```